# Making html tags selectable in GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt

I'm trying to display an html source ( without interpretation ) and I'd like all the nodes to be selectable (p, div, etc..). Something like in firebug where if I click on a node I can get it's properties. Does anybody have an idea how to do that or where to start ?

Answer (score 1):

What about codemirror? Something like this:

http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/mixedtest.html

You'd have to integrate it into GWT via JSNI, but that wouldn't be to hard. It has hooks to get the cursor position etc.